# What happens to the old object if you set a variable equal to a new object?

Tags: c++

Say we have a class X that does *not* have an overloaded `operator=()` function.

```
class X {
    int n;

    X() {n = 0;}
    X(int _n) {n = _n;}
};

int main() {
    X a;    // (1) an object gets constructed here

    // more code...

    a = X(7);    // (2) another object gets constructed here (?)

    // some more code...

    a = X(12);    // (3) yet another object constructed here (?)
    return 0;
}
```

Is a new object constructed at (2)? If it is, what happens to the old object that was constructed at (1)? Is it automatically destructed or deallocated (which is it)? Is it overwritten?

And what happens farther down the code at (3)?

And most importantly, **is there ever a chance of causing a memory leak by writing code like in the above?**

Comment: For a quick and dirty confirmation of when constructors are being called, put a print statement in the constructors. But watch out for the copy and move constructors that may have been generated for you.

Comment: I do not think you can create memory leak without allocating memory dynamically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you need to understand is that there's a lot of "implicit" code generated by the compiler that you, as a novice, don't know about. We'll use your code for `class X` as a direct example:

```
class X {
    int n;
public: //You didn't include this, but this won't work at all unless your constructors are public
    X() {n = 0;}
    X(int _n) {n = _n;}
};
```

Before the code gets turned into Object Code, but after your compiler gets ahold of your class definition, it transforms your class into something that looks (roughly) like this:

```
class X {
    int n;
public:
    X() {n = 0;} //Default-Constructor
    X(int _n) {n = _n;} //Other Constructor
    //GENERATED BY COMPILER
    X(X const& x) {n = x.n;} //Copy-Constructor
    X(X && x) {n = x.n;} //Move-Constructor
    X & operator=(X const& x) {n = x.n; return *this;} //Copy-Assignment
    X & operator=(X && x) {n = x.n; return *this;} //Move-Assignment
    ~X() noexcept {} //Destructor
};
```

The rules for when these members are automatically created are not super-obvious ([A good starting reference here](https://www.slideshare.net/ripplelabs/howard-hinnant-accu2014)), but for now, you can trust that in this case, that's exactly what happens.

So in your `main` function, let's go over what happens, with the specifics called attention to with comments:

```
int main() {
    X a; //Default-Constructor called
    a = X(7);//Other Constructor called, then Move-Assignment operator called,
    //then Destructor called on temporary created by `X(7)`
    a = X(12); //Same as previous line

    return 0;
    //Destructor called on `a`
}
```

We'll add a few more lines to show most (if not all) of the various permutations of these calls:

```
int main() {
    X a; //Default-Constructor
    X b = a; //Copy-Constructor (uses copy-elision to avoid calling Default + copy-assign)
    X c(5); //Other Constructor
    X d{7}; //Also Other Constructor
    X e(); //Declares a function! Probably not what you intended!
    X f{}; //Default-Constructor
    X g = X(8); //Other Constructor (uses copy-elision to avoid calling Other + move-assign + Destructor)
    X h = std::move(b); //Move-Constructor (uses copy-elision to avoid calling Default + move-assign)
    b = c; //Copy-assignment
    b = std::move(d); //Move-assignment
    d = X{15}; //Other Constructor, then Move-Assignment, then Destructor on `X{15}`.
    //e = f; //Will not compile because `e` is a function declaration!
    return 0;
    //Destructor on `h`
    //Destructor on `g`
    //Destructor on `f`
    //Destructor will NOT be called on `e` because `e` was a function declaration, 
    //not an object, and thus has nothing to clean up!
    //Destructor on `d`
    //Destructor on `c`
    //Destructor on `b`
    //Destructor on `a`
}
```

That should cover the basics.

> And most importantly, **is there ever a chance of causing a memory leak by writing code like in the above?**

As written, no. However, suppose your class did something like this instead:

```
class X {
    int * ptr;
public:
    X() {
        ptr = new int{0};
    }
};
```

Now, your code would leak, because every time an `X` was created, you'd have a pointer that never gets deleted.

To solve this, you need to make sure that A) The destructor properly cleans up the pointer, and B) that your copy/move constructors/operators are correct.

```
class X {
    int * ptr;
public:
    X() {
        ptr = new int{0};
    }
    X(int val) {
        ptr = new int{val};
    }
    X(X const& x) : X() {
        *ptr = *(x.ptr);
    }
    X(X && x) : X() {
        std::swap(ptr, x.ptr);
    }
    X & operator=(X const& x) {
        *ptr = *(x.ptr);
        return *this;
    }
    X & operator=(X && x) {
        std::swap(ptr, x.ptr);
        return *this;
    }
    ~X() noexcept {
        delete ptr;
    }
};
```

This code will not leak memory if used as-is in either your `main` function or mine. But of course, it doesn't stop the leaks if you do something like this:

```
int main() {
    X * ptr = new X{};
    return 0;
    //Whelp.
}
```

In general, if you never need to use pointers at all, it's recommended you use something like `std::unique_ptr` instead, as it gives most of this stuff for free.

```
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<X> ptr{new X{}};
    return 0;
    //Destructor called on *ptr
    //`delete` called on ptr
}
```

And it's a good idea in your original class, with a caveat that, unless you explicitly change it, your class won't by copyable anymore (though it'll still be movable):

```
class X {
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr;
public:
    X() {
        ptr.reset(new int{0});
    }
    X(int val) {
        ptr.reset(new int{val});
    }
    //X(X && x); //auto generated by compiler
    //X & operator=(X && x); //auto generated by compiler
    //~X() noexcept; //auto generated by compiler

    //X(X const& x); //Deleted by compiler
    //X & operator=(X const& x); //Deleted by compiler
};
```

We can see the changes in my previous version of `main`:

```
int main() {
    X a; //Default-Constructor
    //X b = a; //Was Copy-Constructor, no longer compiles
    X c(5); //Other Constructor
    X d{7}; //Also Other Constructor
    X f{}; //Default-Constructor
    X g = X(8); //Other Constructor (uses copy-elision to avoid calling Other + move-assign + Destructor)
    X h = std::move(c); //Move-Constructor (uses copy-elision to avoid calling Default + move-assign)
    //b = c; //Was Copy-assignment, no longer compiles
    c = std::move(d); //Move-assignment
    d = X{15}; //Other Constructor, then Move-Assignment, then Destructor on `X{15}`.
    return 0;
    //Destructor on `h`
    //Destructor on `g`
    //Destructor on `f`
    //Destructor on `d`
    //Destructor on `c`
    //Destructor on `a`
}
```

If you want to use `std::unique_ptr`, but also want the resulting class to be copyable, you'll need to implement the copy constructor yourself using the techniques I discussed.

And that should be about it! Let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: Many things described here don't actually happen due to copy elision and return value optimization. It's still useful for those who want to understand the gory details.

Comment: @proski I tried to call out specific cases where Copy Ellision would occur, are there any cases in my examples that I failed to identify? Also, there's very few function calls in this code, so where is RVO occurring?

Comment: Sorry, I missed it! I searched for "elision" in the reply and could not find it. It turns out it was misspelled.

Comment: @proski Hmm. Fixed.

Answer (score 7):

At point (2) three things happen:

1. A temp object is constructed using the `X(int _n)` constructor.
2. The default assignment operator is used to copy the contents of the temporary to `a`.
3. The temporary goes out of scope and its default destructor is invoked.

The same thing happens at point (3).

At the end of the function, the default destructor on `a` is invoked.

Comment: At step 2 shouldn't it be 'default copy assignment operator' instead?

Comment: what do mean by `copy the temporary to a` ? Is it same as `copy temporary object to old object` ?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, it should be the assignment operator.  Fixed.

Comment: Also default destructor invoked before point (3) or after `return 0` ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan Yes, the old object is `a`.  Also, the destructor for the temp object at (3) is invoked before the `return` statement.

Answer (score -1):

> Is a new object constructed at (2)?

Yes, the temporary object `X(7)`. But it gets destroyed right at the end of the statement.

> If it is, what happens to the old object that was constructed at (1)?

Its default `operator=` that was generated by the compiler is called, passing in the temporary object `X(7)`.

> Is it automatically destructed or deallocated (which is it)?

Not in the assignment. Its deallocated when the function exits though.

> Is it overwritten?

Only the value of its member `n` changes, but that can be thought of as being overwritten.

> And what happens farther down the code at (3)?

The same as in (2).

> is there ever a chance of causing a memory leak by writing code like in the above?

Yes, if you allocate dynamic memory or some other resource, which you're not doing here.

Comment: "No destructors are called" this is incorrect statement

Comment: There are a default `operator=` and a default `~X`.

Comment: @emlai (2): A temporary `X` is created, assigned to `a` and the the temporary `X` is destroyed. And the same with (3)

Comment: @emlai yes destructors for temporaries would be called, unless temporraries would be eliminated by optimization.

Comment: @emlai _"No destructors are called and no deallocation happens."_ Huh what?

Comment: @Slava when destructors called at the end of scope or at assignment statement of (2)

Comment: @AbhishekAryan temporaries are destructed at the end of statement (unless their lifetime is extended by reference)

Comment: @Slava The question is about the class X specifically, which is trivially destructible. Since a trivial destructor literally does nothing, it's not clear to me how "no destructors are called" can be an incorrect statement. Neither gcc nor clang "call" the destructor in any sense even without any optimizations on.

Comment: @NirFriedman from language point of view object is destroyed and destructor is invoked. The fact that dtor is noop is irelevant in this question.